# CORS accepting arbitrary origin with GET but not with OPTIONS

Tags: web-application, web-service, api, cors

I'm testing an API, which allows an arbitrary origin on `POST`/`GET` requests, by responding with the CORS header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

However, with `OPTIONS` requests and an arbitrary origin, the web service does **not** respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, it does not use the response header at all.

This means that any CORS preflight requests with an arbitrary Origin, would fail.

I don't see the point in having the CORS response header for `GET`/`POST` requests, but not the `OPTIONS` request. However, I also can't provide an example for a vulnerability or how this may be exploited.

**Q:** Is it safe to say that does not pose a vulnerability, but is just bad practice?

Comment: is that your api or another application ?

Comment: No, I've been tasked to perform a penetration test. It's an API used by mobile applications and directly by developers in the backend.

Comment: This is a vulnerability because you can avoid preflighting. There's some info [here](https://medium.com/@praveen.beatle/avoiding-pre-flight-options-calls-on-cors-requests-baba9692c21a)

Comment: I don't see how I can avoid preflight requests here. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I've noticed that _Cloudflare for Teams_ exhibits the behaviour described by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Is it safe to say that does not pose a vulnerability, but is just bad practice?

Since it's an API and *assuming* it requires `Authorization` header for all requests, it's safe to say that it doesn't pose a vulnerability. The behavior, however, limits communication to same-domain.

It's worth noting that not all requests are preflighted. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests for more details.

An API expects, *if properly configured*, a proper `Content-type` header and an authorization header which in most cases is `Authorization`. If a request sets a "[forbidden header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name)" or an unsafe `Content-type`, it's always preflighted. And as such, no other domain would be able to send an authenticated request at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a way to allow browsers to make unauthenticated requests against the site, but not authenticated ones. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` doesn't support authenticated CORS requests anyhow - it's a violation of the spec to specify that and also specify `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and conforming browsers would ignore that - but simple (GET/POST/HEAD, no custom headers, only content types supported by HTML forms) requests made *without* credentials will work fine and the requesting site will be able to see the response.

There's no security impact of configuring CORS this way *EDIT: provided that the server doesn't have any non-credentials-based authorization (that is, it doesn't trust any clients based *purely* on things like being on the same LAN or loopback server, or the request coming from a specific IP)*; the server for the other origin (or any host controlled by a hypothetical attacker) could just send its own request to the target site, retrieve the resource that is available unauthenticated, and send it to the browser. The advantage to setting this header is that the server can say "hey, go ask some other site for this info yourself" and the client-side code will be allowed to do that (this reduces other-origin server activity and network load, and exposes where the requests are ultimately coming from to the target site).

Some web scanners still report `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` as inherently vulnerable; this is wrong and their developers should feel bad.

Comment: *a way to allow browsers to make unauthenticated requests against the site, but not authenticated ones*. The OP writes that the preflight response doesn't contain any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. In that case, if the resource is accessed via a CORS request, there's no way its preflight check would succeed.

Comment: True, but irrelevant to security (unless the API server is not publicly accessible). The point I was making about ACAO: * is that it's not security-relevant (and gave the reason why it exists at all). The fact that it won't work for non-simple CORS requests is still not going to impact security at all (though it might be inconvenient for third parties that want to use the API for something).

Comment: A `ACAO: *` CORS policy is relevant to security in some contexts; see, for example, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227779/concrete-example-of-how-can-access-control-allow-origin-cause-security-risks/254684#254684

Comment: I specified the context, @jub0bs. "(unless the API server is not publicly accessible)". I suppose "publicly accessible" is too specific - the actual case is "unless the API server is reachable from the victim's browser but not from any host the attacker controls" - but it rounds off pretty well to "not publicly accessible". I'll edit it into the answer though.

Comment: No worries, I'm nitpicking :)

Comment: I can't fix it myself because the edit would be under 6 chars, but the value of the ACAC header is case-sensitive: `true`.

Comment: Huh! Header names are often case-insensitive, I guess it's not a shock for values to be case-sensitive, but I wouldn't have predicted it. Fixed, and thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem. And I should have quoted the source of truth on this: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials