# Is there an issue if application responds with access control allow origin * but there is no allow credentials header?

Tags: web-application, cors, same-origin-policy

Since application is not responding with allow credentials header, an attacker can't craft cross domain request with cookies, but I was wondering if allow origin * alone (Without credentials being true) can be exploited?

I know allow origin can't be * if allow credentials header is true, what am asking is that is this alone a flaw, is this exploitable in any way?

Comment: This fully depends on your unknown application. Can anything be done there without cookies?

Comment: No, without cookie there's no way to identify a user. Does this mean ACAO header being * is useless in this case?

Comment: Does everything in your application even require a user? Again, this question cannot be answered with the current amount of information.

Comment: Yes, most part of the application is only available to authenticated users which requires cookies.

Comment: Unauthenticated user on this application have access to only static pages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concrete example of how can Access-Control-Allow-Origin:\* cause security risks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227779/concrete-example-of-how-can-access-control-allow-origin-cause-security-risks)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an issue if application responds with access control allow origin * but there is no allow credentials header?

This question is literally exactly the same as:

> Is there an issue if application responds with access control allow origin *?

And that question is already answered at [Concrete example of how can Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* cause security risks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227779/concrete-example-of-how-can-access-control-allow-origin-cause-security-risks)

Beyond that, CORS does not inherently prevent CSRF attacks; you still need a way to block those. That's true even if you don't return any ACAO: header at all, though.

Answer (score -1):

No, if the server's API follows REST principles (which it should).

If in a fetch with `GET` you set `credentials: "include"` then the request *will* be performed and credentials *will* be included. But:

1. response's content won't be made available to the browser when either `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false` (or if either of them is missing). So the client won't be able to read the response even if the server responded with something user-specific.
2. since this is a `GET` request then the server shouldn't *do* anything state-changing (this is the "follow REST" part)

Using `POST`, `PUT` or `DELETE` in a cross-origin fetch with `credentials: "include"` will require a preflight request beforehand -- to ask the server if these methods are allowed to be performed with credentials. So if the server *does allow* credentialed state-changing requests then it must reply to the preflight with headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://the-clients-origin.com` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

(There is a slight exception to the previous for `POST` requests with content-types either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain`. These are there for cross-origin form-submit handlers (someone correct me on this).)

Read more on [MDN: CORS: Simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) or [Fetch specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials).

Comment: This is wrong in multiple ways! Perhaps most centrally, POST requests do *NOT* inherently require pre-flights! POST *might* require a preflight depending on conditions, but so can GET. The distinction is "simple" requests (those that could be made using an HTML form, which does allow POST) aren't preflighted; everything else is. **CORS does not inherently prevent CSRF!**

Comment: @CBHacking  The original question isn't about whether something requires a preflight or not and also not directly about CSRF, but about whether `access-control-allow-origin: *` can be exploited. So for GET and HEAD regardless of if there is a preflight or not they shouldn't be exploitable as per REST they shouldn't cause a state change on the server, neither won't they show the response if credentials were included.

The exception content types where a POST request doesn't require a preflight are mentioned at the end in parenthesis.

Surely the answer could be improved, but how?